# Insert React component into a String variable with html content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, replace, jsx

I need to insert a React component into a String variable that contains html content.
This variable will be render with dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

I replace my placeholder "!#ShareButton" with the content of my React component, but it renders [object Object] instead of the component itself

React component:

```
const ShareThis = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div class="one-line">{text}</div>
)}

export default ShareThis
```

var content (string variable with html content)

```
<p>Text 1</p>
!#ShareButton
<p>Text 2</p>
```

Page:

```
const htmlcontent = content.replace(/!#ShareThis/g,
  <ShareThis
    text="Hello"
  />)

return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlcontent }} />
)
```

Result:

```
Text 1
[object Object]
Text 2
```

**Do you know how to insert a React component into a String variable with html content?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render React component as `innerHTML` because its an object, don't confuse between [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) and HTML.

To solve it your need `content` to be a valid `HTML`.

Can be done by making `ShareThis` a function returning a valid `HTML` as a string:

```
const ShareThis = ({ text }) => {
  return `<div class="one-line">${text}</div>`;
};

const content = `
<p>Text 1</p>
!#ShareButton
<p>Text 2</p>
`;

const htmlcontent = content.replace(
  /!#ShareButton/g,
  ShareThis({ text: "Hello" })
);

const App = () => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlcontent }} />;
};
```

> Note that you have a typo in regex expression: `/!#ShareButton/`

[image: Edit green-sound-n5fvc]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what use case are you trying to solve using this but you can edit your **shareThis** function like this to return html as a string to use it as **innerHtml** later:

```
const ShareThis = ({ text }) => {return (
   `<div class="one-line">${text}</div>`
)}
export default ShareThis
```

This should work..

Answer (score 0):

Another possible alternative would be to use the utility [React HTML Parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser) which can convert HTML strings into react components ([JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)).

Building on the example provided by Dennis:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

const ShareThis = ({ text }) => {
  return `<div class="one-line">${text}</div>`;
};

const content = `
<p>Text 1</p>
!#ShareButton
<p>Text 2</p>
`;

const htmlcontent = content.replace(
  /!#ShareButton/g,
  ShareThis({ text: "Hello" })
);

export default function App() {
  return <div>{ReactHtmlParser(htmlcontent)}</div>;
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-html-parser-hutit)